# Convert all files in project from tab to space with TextMate

Tags: textmate

I made some mistakes while coding: use tab instead of space. I didn't turn on my soft tab. I know TextMate has an option to convert tab to space, but for each file, one by one.

Is there a way to convert entire project to space from tab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just do a regex based search/replace in project.

If I remember correctly, searching for  (4 spaces) and replacing all occurences with `\t` with the regex checkbox checked will do the trick.